# HTML/CSS - Headings for each "level" of unordered list

Tags: html, css

I would like to use the heirarchical benefits of using nested unordered lists, but I need to identify each "level" at the top like a table column header. For example, given this unordered list:

- Product 1
  - Part 1
    - Subpart 1
    - Subpart 2
  - Part 2
- Product 2
  - Part 1
  - Part 2

I would like it so that all "Products" are aligned with each other, and have a single heading at the top which says "Products". There would then be a "Parts" heading, and a "Subparts" heading as well. I suppose I could just have a table directly above the unordered list then make the levels line up with it, but I get the feeling there's probably a better way. Thanks!

Comment: This is no question for stackoverflow. You should ask this on http://doctype.com/ (see faq)

Comment: Didn't realize all those partner sites existed, I'll check them out. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I missunderstood something here. You want to do this programmatically. So it isnt a web design question, is it? Do you want to do this with javascript or by dynamically creating the page on the server side? You should update the tags of your question and make it clearer how you want to archieve this. Anyways, I deleted my answer, as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Definition List (dl) and style your dt's as your headers and put your other lists in your dd's.  This would be a good approach semantically if the list you are using is really a set of terms and their associated definitions.

[Definition List Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_dl.asp)

Example:

```
<dl>
<dt>Product 1</dt>
<dd>
   <ul>
     <li>Parts</li>
   </ul>
</dl>

/*CSS*/
dt{font-weight:bold;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<li>Product1
    <ul>
     <li>Part1
         <ul>
         <li>Subpart1</li>
         <li>Subpart2</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Product1
     <ul>
     <li>Part1</li>
     <li>Part1</li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Result:

- Product1

  - Part1

    - Subpart1
    - Subpart2

- Product 2

  - Part1
  - Part1